# Clarifications for FHIR R4 string element

Tags: hl7-fhir

There are a couple of things that I am having trouble with regarding HL7 FHIR R4 strings (https://www.hl7.org/fhir/datatypes.html#string):

1. The specification mentions: *Note that strings SHALL NOT exceed 1MB (1024*1024 characters) in size*. The trouble I am having with this is that 1024x1024 Unicode characters are not always 1MB in size. Besides that it is unclear to me what Unicode encoding is meant here, and I will assume the reasonable UTF-8 since that is the default for both XML and JSON. For example the character '' needs 4 bytes to encode, therefore 1024x1024 of such characters would be 4MB in size. The Regex-es in the notes, though not normative, make this a bit clearer, but not much. It states that codes up to FFFF are ok, which means a max. byte use of 3 per characters which would still exceed the 1MB limit by a factor of 3. My interpretation is that we would like a reasonable limit that doesn't open up any denial-of-service attacks. Therefore I would like to suggest keeping the meaningful 1MB limit but drop the number of characters requirement OR add it as a separate requirement.
2. The specification mentions: *Therefore strings SHOULD always contain non-whitespace content*. It does not mention what it considers whitespace. Is this just the three codes mentioned earlier representing horizontal tab, carriage return and line feed or are more exotic whitespace characters also prohibited, like next line or no-break space?

Ok, that about sums up my questions about the *string* specifications. Hope that someone can help me out.

Best,

Dirk

Comment: Fyi, if you feel anything is unclear in the documentation or can be improved, you can always submit a change request. Details at https://confluence.hl7.org/display/FHIR/Change+Requests.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will very likely do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. The rule is clearly expressed in characters explicitly *because* Unicode characters have variable length.  There is no maximum in bytes, only in characters (though given Unicode rules, you could calculate what the maximum possible length in bytes might be).  If you feel this isn't sufficiently clear, feel free to submit a change request.
2. The expectation is a string SHOULD always have textual content.  If you have nothing to say, omit the element.  Trying to work around the "no empty string" limitation by transmitting a non-breaking space or some other non-visible character to meet the non-empty requirement while not actually conveying any human-readable information would be contrary to the intent of the specification.  We don't demand that systems enforce this because trying to figure out all the creative ways implementers might have of conveying "no useful text" with Unicode isn't terribly practical.  I believe the Java code just does a trim() and compares the result to empty string.

Comment: Let me summarize what I think you are saying:
1. Since the rule also clearly specifies the max size in bytes (1MB) I am reading your answer as: In the specification the max. amount of characters rule is leading and the 1MB limit is only mentioned to illustrate what it could be if you'd only use ASCII characters in UTF-8. So it is fine for a string to be any size as long as it's not more than 1024*1024 characters.

Comment: 2. A string containing non-whitespace characters is discouraged, but not to be enforced and therefore not normative. In short: a sender is encouraged to not use only whitespace characters in a string but a receiver is not expected to enforce it. 
Please let me

Comment: The MB refers to 1024x1024, not to bytes.  You're allowed to have a maximum of 1,048,576 unicode characters, irrespective of how many bytes that takes.

Systems are allowed but not required to reject instances that contain values that are only whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Since MB is commonly understood to refer to mega bytes it is commonly understood to refer to 2^20 bytes I think it would help to be explicit about it not being bytes.

Comment: Can you submit a change request against the spec?

Comment: I chipped in on this issue on JIRA: https://jira.hl7.org/browse/FHIR-36641?focusedCommentId=200738&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.